# How to return XML Tree from Controller in WEB2PY?

Tags: python, xml, web, web2py

I have xml tree built in controller of web2py.

Now I want to return this tree and print the whole xml tree in view on web2py.

How do I do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: You know how to convert etree to string, so just write it to the response.

Comment: I have converted into string, but in view should I just print that string and it would print the xml tree ? Could you give little more detail. I am implementing for first time

Answer (score 2):

If you want the XML to be human readable in an HTML page, then just do:

```
{{=my_xml_string}}
```

In that case, the XML markup will be escaped so it will be viewable when rendered as HTML.

If you want the raw XML inserted into the view (without escaping), then do:

```
{{=XML(my_xml_string)}}
```

Comment: Thanks! Anthony, it was real helpful.
But, When I run the view with {{=XML(my_xml_string)}}, the output is just text without any XML format. Not sure, what is the issue ?
Thanks !

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what you put inside XML()? Presumably it was not actually a string of XML.

Comment: I create a xml data but while reading back and printing it would have removed all xml tags and only data would be printing

Comment: You probably need to check the documentation on the library you are using (may warrant a separate SO question).